# Prove or Disprove that $\left|\frac{e^{2i\theta} -2e^{i\theta} - 1}{e^{2i\theta} + 2e^{i\theta} -1}\right| = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove or disprove that

$$\left|\frac{e^{2i\theta} -2e^{i\theta} - 1}{e^{2i\theta} + 2e^{i\theta} -1}\right| = 1$$

This is a step in an attempt to solve a much larger problem, thus I'm fairly sure it's true but not absolutely sure.  It looks like it should be simple but it's resisted all my attempts so far.

Comment: If we may know, what is the "larger problem"?

Comment: I don't see why the larger problem matters, the only reason I mentioned it was to give the reason why I wasn't sure if it was true or not.

Comment: @Thoth, it matters because my intellectual curiosity matters to me. That is why I asked. Also, I believe it may have piquanted the curiosity of others.

Comment: I'm trying to find a conformal map from the slit open unit disk to the open unit disk which takes boundary to boundary.  I have my conformal map but I'm not sure if conformal maps always take boundary to boundary, thus I was trying to prove it did for my particular conformal map, which in this case is $-\frac{z-i2\sqrt{r}e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}} - 1}{z+i2\sqrt{r}e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}} - 1}$   This conformal map wont give exactly the case I'm looking at above, I tweaked it a bit, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: There is indeed a larger problem : $\forall \theta_1,\theta_2, \ \ \left|\frac{e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2)}+1-2e^{i \theta_1}}{e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2)}+1-2e^{i\theta_2}}\right|=1$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is true.

$$|z - \frac{1}{z} -2 | = |z - \frac{1}{z} + 2|$$

where $z = e^{i\theta}$, since $\Re(z - \frac{1}{z}) = 0$.

Geometrically, $z - \frac{1}{z}$ lies on the $y$-axis (perpendicular bisector of $(2,0)$ and $(-2,0)$).

Comment: Ah nicely done, thank you.

Comment: @Thoth: You are welcome!

Answer (score 6):

Divide by $e^{i\theta}$ the numerator and denominator :
$$\left|\frac{e^{2i\theta} -2e^{i\theta} - 1}{e^{2i\theta} + 2e^{i\theta} -1}\right|=\left|\frac{e^{i\theta} -2 - e^{-i\theta}}{e^{i\theta} +2 - e^{-i\theta}}\right|$$
Think at the complex conjuguate of the numerator and conclude!

Comment: Seems like you were getting at the same thing as Aryabhata, +1.

Comment: @Thoth: yes. I hope that both helped, fine continuation,

Answer (score 2):

Taking the squared norm of the numerator and denominator separately,
$$
\eqalign{
\left|e^{ 2i\theta}\pm e^{ i\theta}-1\right|^2 &=
\left(e^{ 2i\theta}\pm e^{ i\theta}-1\right)\cdot
\left(e^{-2i\theta}\pm e^{-i\theta}-1\right)\\ &
\matrix{=& 1 & \pm2e^{ i\theta} &         -e^{2i\theta} \\\\
         &     \pm2e^{-i\theta} & +4 & \mp2e^{ i\theta} \\\\
         &        -e^{2i\theta} &      \mp2e^{-i\theta} & +1 }
\\\\ &= 6 - 2\cos 2\theta \pm 2\cos\theta \mp 2\cos\theta
\\\\ &= 6 - 2\cos 2\theta\,.
}
$$
Notice, however, that this no longer depends on the sign,
i.e. it is the same for the numerator and denominator.

But I admit, I like @Raymond's and @Aryabhata's answers much better!